# Arraylist trouble, package doesn't exist compiler error

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm getting "package m1 and m2 does not exist" when I compile this code, any help would be appreciated, I'm brand new at working with Arraylists. I know it's very close so any assistance to get it to compile and output would be greatly appreciated!

```
2 errors found:
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/Member.java  [line: 66]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/Member.java:66: package m1 does not exist
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/Member.java  [line: 72]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/Member.java:72: package m2 does not exist



import java.util.*;


public class Member {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<String>();


    public Member() {
        id = 0;
        name = "John Doe";
    }

    public Member(int pId, String pName) {
        id = pId;
        name = pName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int pId) {
        id = pId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String pName) {
        name = pName;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(ArrayList<String> pBooks) {
        books = pBooks;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append("ID: " + getId() + "  Member: " + getName() + "\n");
        buf.append("Book: " + books + "\n");
    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = {"Java Data Structures", "The Bible", "Grapes of Wrath",
                "Goldfinger", "Sam I Am", "The Cat in the Hat", "Shawshenk Redemption",
                "Green Eggs and Ham", "Linus and Lucy", "Abraham Lincoln"};

        Member m1 = new Member();
        m1.setId(431);
        m1.setName("William Wallace");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            m1.ArrayList<String> books = list[i];
        }

        Member m2 = new Member(7010, "Bonny Clyde");
        for (int i = 5; i < list.length; i++) {
            int x = i - 5;
            m2.ArrayList<String> books = list[i];
        }
        System.out.println(m1.toString());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(m2.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: What's your package statement in that file?

Comment: @KubaRakoczy What do you mean by package statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m1.ArrayList<String> books = list[i]`

replace this with `m1.books.add(list[i])`, and the same for `m2`

Comment: I have one question, I can't get my toString method to work, I'm getting a missing return statement and I don't know how to print the Arraylist from there, here's how I did it with an array:

Comment: public String toString(){
   StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
   buf.append("ID: " + getId() + "  Member: " + getName() + "\n");
   for(int x=0; x<books.length; x++ ) {
    buf.append("Book: " + books[x] + "\n");
   }
   return buf.toString();
  }

Comment: Please don't try to give us several lines of code in a comment.  Either edit the original question with the code--or, in this case, since the code isn't related to your question, ask a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: You can loop through list same as you do with arrays. Just use `books.get(x)` instead of `books[x]` and `books.size()` instead of `books.length`. Better yet, get rid of index and just do `for(String book: books) buf.append("Book: ").append(book).append("\n);` This works for arrays and lists alike.

Comment: @Dima Thank you, it compiles now, but does not run. I'm getting an out of bounds exception. Any clue how I could fix that?